# Problem with Border Layout component positioning

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, border-layout

I really don't know how to make the south panel appear without make the buttons go up. Maybe i need to change the layout from border layout to another one, I don't know...

**---------->My Code:**

```
public class a1211 extends JFrame {

    private final JButton OK; 
    private final JButton cancel;
    private final JButton setup; 
    private final JButton help;
    private final JPanel buttonPanel;
    private final JLabel printQuality;
    private final JComboBox<String> quality; 
    private final String[] qualityNames = { "High", "Low", "Medium" };
    private final JCheckBox printToFile;
    private final JPanel southPanel;

    public a1211() {
        super("Printer");          

        OK = new JButton("OK");
        cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        setup = new JButton("Setup...");
        help = new JButton("Help");
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 5, 5));
        buttonPanel.add(OK);
        buttonPanel.add(cancel);
        buttonPanel.add(setup);
        buttonPanel.add(help);

        printQuality = new JLabel("Print Quality:");
        quality = new JComboBox<String>(qualityNames);
        printToFile = new JCheckBox("Print To File");
        southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.add(printQuality);
        southPanel.add(quality);
        southPanel.add(printToFile);

        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a1211 a1211 = new a1211();
        a1211.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
        a1211.setSize(400, 150);
        a1211.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**---------->What this code make:**

[image]

**---------->What it should make:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7UWG.jpg]

Comment: The north and south areas go the full width of the layout. The east and west areas, as you have found out, are between the north and south areas.

Comment: What you can do, however. is to use and extra JPanel and put the buttons in the east area of the outer JPanel, and then put the other JPanel in the center and use that as you want.

Comment: Did not get it, how to make this? And just to let you know this excirse still has more difficult things to do than this. At the moment i need only this solved.

Comment: I already have 2 Jpanel's, one in BorderLayout.EAST of the frame and another one in BorderLayout.SOUTH of the frame.

Comment: Take outerPanel and put a BorderLayout on it. Put your button panel in the east area. Create an innerPanel, also with a BorderLayout. Put this in the center area of outerPanel. Then put all your other panels into innerPanel (except for the button panel, because you've already put that into outerPanel). Then the buttonPanel will take up the full height of the window.

Comment: @NomadMaker: you might need to make an answer

Comment: *" this excirse still has more difficult things to do than this."* If that translates to 'more components' .. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the entire GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. Another tip: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.